# More than one global prefix in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.setGlobalPrefix("v1");
  app.setGlobalPrefix("v2");

  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

I want two versions of my APIs so want to know how to set the two global prefix ?

Answer (score 3):

You could create individual factories by initializing one with `NestFactoryStatic`, setting a global prefix for this factory by calling `setGlobalPrefix` and initializing it by calling the `init` method.

Here is an example on how you would do this, derived from this [source](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/global-prefix-for-a-module-route-tree):

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    const server = express();
    const config = require('../../etc/config.js');

    const apiFactory = new NestFactoryStatic();
    const api = await apiFactory.create(ApiModule, server);
    api.setGlobalPrefix("/api/v1");
    await api.init();

    const adminFactory = new NestFactoryStatic();
    const admin = await adminFactory.create(AdminModule, server);
    admin.setGlobalPrefix("/admin");
    await admin.init();

    http.createServer(server).listen(config.server.port);
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this using `setGlobalPrefix`, also there's no support for this mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix). But you could just create two controllers for each version and set the base path there:

```
@Controller('/v1')
export class ApiControllerV1 {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}

@Controller('/v2')
export class ApiControllerV2 {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Gaurav: Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.setGlobalPrefix(':version(v1:v2)');

or

app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    prefix: 'v',
    defaultVersion: ['v1', 'v2']
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can

```
app.setGlobalPrefix("v1|v2");
```

like regex.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33458335)

Comment: It's not work for me.