# How can set many globalprefix for nestjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, nestjs, prefix

I want set many Global Prefix for my app like this :

**admin/products**
**admin/users**
**admin/...**

**api/products**
**api/search**
**api/...**

**shop/products**
**shop/cart**
**shop/...**

i can set one globalprefix into main.ts
`app.setGlobalPrefix('api')`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67210684/518257 this answer will be help to you

Answer (score -1):

Use `app.setGlobalPrefix('api')` only for a global prefix.
If you want the same prefix for many controllers, you must write it in each controller, like:

```
@Controller('shop/products')
```

You can also define a constant somewhere and reuse it every time:

```
const shopPrefix: string = 'shop';    
@Controller(`${shopPrefix}/products`)
```